# The hydrator settings are ignored in Apigility

Tags: php, zend-framework2, settings, laminas-api-tools

In Apigility it's possible to set a `Hydrator` for every `Entity` -- either over the Apigility UI

[image]

or directly in the `module.config.php`, e.g.:

```
return array(
    ...
    'zf-hal' => array(
        'metadata_map' => array(
            'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectEntity' => array(
                'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'route_name' => 'portfolio.rest.project',
                'route_identifier_name' => 'id',
                'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ObjectProperty',
                // 'hydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator',
            ),
            ...
        ),
        ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

See also the [documentation](https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/first-rest-service).

Currently I'm using the [`ClassMethods`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Stdlib/Hydrator/ClassMethods.php) hydrator for all my entities.

Now I tried to change the setting to a custom hydrator. I've also tried another Zend hydrator. But whatever I do, only the hydrated I have defined in the `module.config.php is ignored.

**EDIT**: It works for sigle entities, but not for collections. I've checked this with the debugger and see: when I retieve a collection, my custom hydrator doesn't get called. I cannot find out, which hydrator is actually being used -- I set breakpoints and even wrote `die()`s in the `extract()` and `hydrate()` methods of all hydrators (`ArraySerializable`, `ClassMethods`, `ObjectProperty`, `Reflection`, and also in my custom `ProjectHydrator`), but the application didn't notice that at all and is still working. Seems so, that no hydration is made at all...

**What is wrong here and how to get hydration settings working correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

When you defined the Entity class for your service, you also have the option to configure the Collection entity for your service. You need to to associate your hydrator to the Collection entity in your metadata.

```
return [
    'zf-rest' => [
        'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\Controller' => [
            // other config
            'entity_class' => 'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectEntity',
            'collection_class' => 'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectCollection',
        ]
    ],
    'zf-hal' => [
        'metadata_map' => [
            'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectEntity' => [
                // other config
                'hydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator'
            ],
            'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectCollection' => [
                // other config
                'hydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectCollectionHydrator'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Old but found this:
For collectionRender the hydrator is not called
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/Plugin/Hal.php#L570

For entityRender is:
https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-hal/blob/master/src/Plugin/Hal.php#L695

Need to call issue for that.

Edit[07.10.16]:

I was wrong with that.

My solution works with Apigility 1.3. Didn't test earlier versions.

You can use `Zend\\Hydrator\\DelegatingHydrator`

```
        'metadata_map' => array(
        'Test\\DomainModel\\UseCase\\Query\\ShowTask\\Response\\Task' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'uuid',
            'route_name' => 'descriptive-module.rest.task',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'task_id',
            'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Hydrator\\DelegatingHydrator',
        ),
        'Test\\DomainModel\\UseCase\\Query\\ListTask\\Response\\Task' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'uuid',
            'route_name' => 'descriptive-module.rest.task',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'task_id',
            'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Hydrator\\DelegatingHydrator',
        ),
```

First one, for entity.
Second one, elements of returned Collection.

Then in module.config.php

```
   'hydrators' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        \Test\DomainModel\UseCase\Query\ShowTask\Response\Task::class =>
            \TestApi\V1\Rest\Task\Hydrator\ShowTaskHydrator::class,
        \Test\DomainModel\UseCase\Query\ListTask\Response\Task::class =>
            \TestApi\V1\Rest\Task\Hydrator\ListTaskHydrator::class,
    ),
    'factories' => array(),
),
```

`TaskShowHydrator`/`ListTaskHydrator` need implement `Zend\Hydrator\HydratorInterface`