# How to register a custom hydrator in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools, hal

In an Apigility driven ZF2 application I want to use a custom `Hydrator`.

**`Module` class**

```
class Module implements ApigilityProviderInterface {
    ...
    public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                ...
                'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator' => function(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                    $projectHydrator = new ProjectHydrator();
                    $projectHydrator->setImageService($serviceManager->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService'));
                    return $projectHydrator;
                }
            ),
            ...
        );
    }
}
```

**`module.config.php`**

```
...
'zf-hal' => array(
    'metadata_map' => array(
        ...
        'Portfolio\\V2\\Rest\\Project\\ProjectEntity' => array(
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
            'route_name' => 'portfolio.rest.project',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'id',
            // 'hydrator' => 'Zend\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\ClassMethods',
            'hydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator',
        ),
        ...
    ),
),
...
```

It's ignored, when a collection get retrieved, but it's another issue (s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006095/the-hydrator-settings-are-ignored-in-apigility)). When a single entity is required, the hydratin mechanism starts, but it doesn't use my factory, in order to create an instance.

After some debugging I came to this place in the `ZF\Hal\Metadata\Metadata#setHydrator(...)` code:

```
if (is_string($hydrator)) {
    if (null !== $this->hydrators
        && $this->hydrators->has($hydrator)
    ) {
        $hydrator = $this->hydrators->get($hydrator);
    } elseif (class_exists($hydrator)) {
        $hydrator = new $hydrator(); // <-- here
    }
}
```

The custom `Hydrator` gets created directly. (In my case it causes a fatal error, since it's tried then to execute a method on `ProjectHydrator#imageService`, that is not set). I took a look at the `Metadata#hydrators` (of type `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager`) and found only four default `invocables`, that's why `null !== $this->hydrators && $this->hydrators->has($hydrator)` is `false` and a direct instantiating is tried.

So, I guess, I have to register my custom hydrator. Where/how can I do this?

---

**EDIT**:

I move the factory code from `Module#getServiceConfig()` to `Module#getHydratorConfig()`:

```
public function getHydratorConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // V2
            'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator' => function(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                $projectHydrator = new ProjectHydrator();
                $projectHydrator->setImageService($serviceManager->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService'));
                return $projectHydrator;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

The same over the config array in the `module.config.php` (needs an `Factory` class):

**`module.config.php`**

```
return array(
    ...
    'hydrators' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydratorFactory',
        ), 
    ),
);
```

But its ends with an error:

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
>
> File:
>   /var/www/my-project/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:550
>   Message: Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager::get was unable to
>   fetch or create an instance for Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did in your edit using `getHydratorConfig` was correct, the error message you're seeing is caused because within your factory method you're attempting to fetch your image service from the hydrator plugin manager.

The solution is simple, as with other plugin managers you need to call `getServiceLocator()` on the hydrator manager instance in order to get the main service locator (aka the service manager)

So, a small change to your factory method should fix the issue ...

```
public function getHydratorConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // V2
            'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydrator' => function(ServiceManager $serviceManager) {
                $projectHydrator = new ProjectHydrator();
                // get the image service from the main service locator
                $imageService = $serviceManager->getServiceLocator()->get('Portfolio\V2\Rest\ImageService');
                $projectHydrator->setImageService($imageService);
                return $projectHydrator;
            }
        ),
    );
}
```

How it works: The instance passed to the closure as argument is a `Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager`. The `HydratorPluginManager` inherits from the `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager`, that is a child of the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`. But the method `ServiceManager#get(...)` gets logically overridden in the `HydratorPluginManager` and provides only hydrators. Nevertheless it's parent class implements the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`, so we access to its internal `ServiceLocator` and over the `ServiceLocator` to the entire set of the available services.

As an aside, I usually prefer to name the serviceLocator variable in the factory method (`$serviceManager` in your code) so that it reflects the actual plugin manager in use, so for a hydrator factory, `$hydrators`, for a form factory, `$formElemements`, and so forth. I reserve use of `$services` to refer to the main service manager only. I find doing this is a helpful reminder that a `getServiceLocator()` call is necessary for any dependencies not located in that particular manager.

Answer (score -1):

Quick response. Replace `HydratorManager` with a custom one.

In your global config:

```
return array(
  'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => (
        'HydratorManager' => 'MyNamespace\Hydrator\HydratorManagerFactory',
    ),
  ),
);
```

MyNamespace\Hydrator\HydratorManagerFactory.php:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Hydrator;

use Zend\Mvc\Service\HydratorManagerFactory as BaseHydratorManagerFactory;

class HydratorManagerFactory extends BaseHydratorManagerFactory
{
    const PLUGIN_MANAGER_CLASS = 'MyNamespace\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager';
}
```

MyNamespace\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager.php

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Hydrator;

use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager as BaseHydratorPluginManager;

class HydratorPluginManager extends BaseHydratorPluginManager
{
    protected $factories = array(
        'mynamespacehydratorprojecthydrator' => 'MyNamespace\\Hydrator\\ProjectHydratorFactory',
    );
}
```

**Note** the factory will receive an instance of `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager`. You can get the general ServiceLocator calling the method `$services->getServiceLocator()`